# Multi-Locale Chapel Cluster Setup

Tags: installation, parallel-processing, chapel

I am new at the chapel Language and I want to set up a Chapel Multi-locale Cluster.
I have a LAN of computers with Windows installed on all of them. So my specific questions are

1. Should I install LINUX on all machines to be able to use them as a "Locale"? If Yes, I probably need to install Virtual Machines on computers, is it OK? and How can I specifically connect to the Virtual Machines from the server?
2. Should I install Chapel On every single Computer on my cluster? If yes, do all the installations have the same procedure in terms of "Settings"?

In the end, I appreciate it if you offer any doc/video that you have found it useful.

Comment: This isn't a coding issue, I think you'd have a better chance getting good answers if you put your question in a better suited stack site.

Comment: @user1268890—Sorry for the lack of earlier response on this, it seems that our SO bot went offline sometime in the past few months and nobody noticed until today.  I don't have much experience with Chapel on Windows in general, and in a cluster setting specifically.  But I have a vague recollection of some Microsoft engineers successfully running over multiple Windows systems using Windows Subsystem for Linux.  Have you given that a try at all? To your second question, generally there is no need to install Chapel on every system—only to have a shared file system where the executables can live.